# How does self contained function work in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var count = 0;
(function curse() {
  console.log(++count);
  curse();
})();
```

can anybody explain how does this function work? as you can see i have called the function inside of its declaration, then why it does not show any error while i called it before it finishes its declaration? and while i tried it in google console, it loops through to infinity. i don't know what really going on and how does this code execute itself, even though i know the self-executing function in javascript. I will be glad if somebody explains this code. thanks in advance

Comment: There is no prohibition against a function calling itself.  Often times, this needs to be done.  It is called "recursion."  However, when making recursive calls, there has to be some logic to make sure it ends.  Otherwise, you'll get a stack overflow error.

Comment: There's no error because even though the function is referenced before the definition is complete, the function is not actually *called* until *after* its definition is complete.

Comment: Read this, it may help you understand: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Comment: No, first the function is defined: `function curse() {console.log(++count);curse();}`, then it is called as an IIFE `(...)()` and during that first call, when JS starts to actually execute the code inside the function, the function calles itself `curse()`. That's called a recursion.

Comment: if its recursive function, then why it does not stop after 2nd cycle. I mean, the insider function may run the function once and outside parenthesis called once. so overall it should work twice. but it's not what i think. what really going on there

Comment: because during this recursive call, it also comes across this line `curse();` and calls itself another time, and then another time, ... And since you've not defined any conditions to ever NOT call itself, this function will call itself recursively untill your browser terminates the execution of Javascript on that page, after approximately 30 seconds.

Comment: Perhaps you will understand it better if it's expanded: ``{ var curse = function() { console.log(++count); curse(); }; curse(); }``

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 0;
(function curse() {
  console.log(++count);
  curse();
})();
```

This can be explained using a divide and conquer approach.

1.- Explanation for:

```
(function someFnc(){})()
```

---

When you declare a function, this will actually return a `Function` object which can be assigned to a variable:

```
var someFnc = function(){};
```

Afterwards, you can do something with this variable like to actually call the function like so:

```
someFnc();
```

In your case, instead of assigning the return value of the declaration to some variable, You're actually calling the function right away by doing this:

```
(function foo())();
```

Long story short, the latter will assure that the function gets called immediately after being declared.

2.- Explanation for `function curse(){ console.log(++count); curse(); }`

---

The `++count` is simply summing 1 to the variable count and after that it gets printed in console.

```
Recursion
```

The second part of this code is the interesting part, is a function that calls itself, this notion is perfectly valid and is called 'Recursion'.

I'll explain recursion with an example using pseudocode:

`Chain of events:` 
The function `curse` is called
The variable count is increased by 1
The variable is printed to console
The function `curse` is called
The variable count is increased by 1
The variable is printed to console
The function `curse` is called
The variable count is increased by 1
The variable is printed to console

and so on...

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you write:

```js
()();
```

You create an IIFE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

In this case, JavaScript try to run the function, inside first brackets,
and compute result of this function,
and return this result, from function-expression.

2. If you write some expression in the first brackets, you'll got an error:

```js
(1+2)(); //Uncaught TypeError: 3 is not a function
```

3. If you write:

```
(function(){ return 1+2; })(); //3
```

You'll get 3, as an int.

4. If you write:

```js
var x = (function(){ return 1+2; })(); //3 returns and write in x;
console.log('x', x); //3
```

5. Next, thing, your function is named.
   If you write:

```js
(function curse() {})();
```

JavaScript try to return result of function curse();
The name of this function is available in scope of IIFE (inside first brackets).
If you write:

```js
(function curse() { return 1+2; })();
curse(); //curse is not defined
```

So, curse() is available only in first brackets.

6. This function is recursive, and this not return the result:

```js
function curse() {
  console.log(++count);
  curse();
}
```

So JavaScript can not return result, and continue to compute this infinity times;

7. If you write this, without console.log (this operation took some time):

```js
var count = 0;
(function curse() {
  curse();
})();
```

You'll got an error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

8. Inside your function, at line `console.log(++count);`,
   JavaScript call console.log,
   then get value of count variable
   (it's available in scope of `function curse`,
   because expression writted in the place, where count is available for this place),
   then increment this value `++`,
   show result,
   and save this in variable `count`.
   With each call of the command `console.log(++count);`
   `count` value is increasing,
   but because there is no any end, this increasing infinity.
9. You can also, write the following code,

```js
var count = 0;
(function curse() {
  setTimeout(
    function(){
        console.log(++count);
        curse();
    },1000
  )
})();
```

to reduce the computing power, and see how this working.

Answer (score -3):

You have extra parentheses, which are not needed.

```
var count = 0;

function curse() {
   console.log(++count);
   if (curse < 100) {
      curse();
   }
}
```

Comment: this code does some things completely different. Check these out: [tag:iife]

Comment: @Thomas.  Your link isn't too helpful.  How is it completely different?

Comment: First, now it's a function statement, not an expression, therefore this function will be hoisted and the function name will be registered as a variable in the current scope *(both wasn't the case in the original scope)*. And by removing the `(...)()` part this function is not immediately invoked. The link shows you a whole topic of questions around that pattern, the Immediately Invoked Function Expression [tag:iife]

Comment: I see, but I didn't take OP's concern as how iife's behave.  I understood his concern to be over how recursion works.

Comment: OK, but then you should really rephrase your answer. *"You have extra parentheses, which are not needed."* doesn't reflect that at all, plus this answer doesn't explain anything about recursions at the moment. you've only fixed the "endless loop" in the code; and even that would be nice if you'd have explained it.

Comment: I agree.  I'll man-up and take the down-votes.  However, I made a comment above which I think, together with the example, spells out how to use recursion and avoid infinite recursion.